# How to click and unclick to change color on a button?

Tags: java, click

My Netbeans GUI is set up, so that the color of the original buttons is green (modified the properties). I put code for each of my nine green buttons, that if you click it, it will turn grey as a sign as it's "selected." Now, I can't figure out how if you click it again, that it should turn back to green as "unselected." I think creating a boolean method would work best, but I'm not 100% positive.

```
private void btnTwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    btnTwo.setBackground( backgroundColor );
}
```

That's basically what it is so far, the backgroundColor is grey, and the original color I set it too was green.

Comment: Is this java? can you post some code?

Comment: Yes it is, and that's what I'm trying to figure out. I did something on my edit @Roger

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if condition to check whether the button is selected or not.And based on that condition assign color to button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setEnabled() function so far if it takes true you have to use a color else if it is taking false give a color like:

```
      mybutton.setEnabled(true);

      mybutton.setEnabled(false);
```

or you may use isEnabled() method wether to check the button is enabled or not and then set the appropiate color you want have fun!